# How to change two Input boxes using one slider

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label>One Input Box</label><br>
<input id="A"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="100"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 100){ this.value = 100; return false; }"
>
<br>
<input id="MDLslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="340" oninput="A.value=MDLslider.value"/>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<label>Two Input Boxes for Time?</label><br>
<input id="D"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       placeholder="Minutes"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="59"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
>
<input id="E"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       placeholder="Seconds"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="59"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
>
<input id="TIMEslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="59" oninput="D.value=TIMEslider.value"/>


</body>
</html>
```

Above code includes two sliders. Each slider changes associated input box values.

First slider has only one input box; Second slider has two input boxes.

I am having difficulty with the second slider, which as two input boxes.

Two input boxes each represent ***Minutes*** and ***Seconds***, respectively. I only know how to change one input box at a time. But I want the slider to change both minutes and seconds by corresponding slider position.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that will pass it's value to every input.

Pay attention that seconds input minimum value is -1. This is to allow to change minutes by pressing Down on seconds input. And then function prevents decrementing total number of seconds below 0.

```js
const inpM = document.querySelector("#inp-m");
const inpS = document.querySelector("#inp-s");
const timeSlider = document.querySelector("#time-slider");

function changeTime(seconds) {
    if (seconds < 0) { seconds = 0 }
    if (seconds > 3600) { seconds = 3600 }
    timeSlider.value = seconds;
    inpM.value = ~~(seconds / 60); // ~~ are bitwise operation instead of Math.floor()
    inpS.value = seconds % 60;
};


inpM.addEventListener('input', ()=>{
    const secs = parseInt(inpM.value) * 60 + parseInt(inpS.value);
    changeTime(secs);
});
inpS.addEventListener('input', ()=>{
    const secs = parseInt(inpM.value) * 60 + parseInt(inpS.value);
    changeTime(secs);
});
timeSlider.addEventListener('input', ()=>{
    const secs = parseInt(timeSlider.value);
    changeTime(secs);
});
```

```html
<h2>Two Input Boxes for Time</h2>

<input id="inp-m" type="number" min=0 max=59 size=4 value=0> m
<input id="inp-s" type="number" min=-1 max=60 size=4 value=0> s

<br>
<input id="time-slider" type="range" min=0 max=3600 value=0>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use semicolons (`;`) just like you would in a `script` tag like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label>One Input Box</label><br>
<input id="A"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="100"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 100){ this.value = 100; return false; }"
>
<br>
<input id="MDLslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="340" oninput="A.value=MDLslider.value"/>
<br>
<br>
<br>


<label>Two Input Boxes for Time?</label><br>
<input id="D"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       placeholder="Minutes"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="59"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
>
<input id="E"
       type="number"
       class="occupied"
       placeholder="Seconds"
       required=""
       min="1"
       max="59"
       onkeyup="if(parseInt(this.value) > 59){ this.value = 59; return false; }"
>
<input id="TIMEslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="59" oninput="D.value=TIMEslider.value;E.value=D.value*60"/>


</body>
</html>
```

However, use of inline event listeners is not recommended. Using `addEventListener` is the way to go:

```js
A.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (parseInt(this.value) > 100) {
    this.value = 100;
    return false;
  }
})
MDLslider.addEventListener('input', function() {
  A.value = MDLslider.value;
})
D.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (parseInt(this.value) > 59) {
    this.value = 59;
    return false;
  }
})
E.addEventListener('keyup', function() {
  if (parseInt(this.value) > 59) {
    this.value = 59;
    return false;
  }
})
TIMEslider.addEventListener('input', function() {
  D.value = TIMEslider.value;
  E.value = D.value * 60
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <label>One Input Box</label><br>
  <input id="A" type="number" class="occupied" required="" min="1" max="100" onkeyup="">
  <br>
  <input id="MDLslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="340" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>


  <label>Two Input Boxes for Time?</label><br>
  <input id="D" type="number" class="occupied" placeholder="Minutes" required="" min="1" max="59">
  <input id="E" type="number" class="occupied" placeholder="Seconds" required="" min="1" max="59">
  <input id="TIMEslider" class="occupied" type="range" min="0" max="59" />


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I make the minutes go up only after seconds? For example, as the slider goes up, 1 minute 59 seconds would appear before 2 minutes 0 second.

Comment: @JimO. I don't get what you mean. The 'seconds' input should never be 59 seconds, since it's the 'minutes' input multiplied by 60.

Comment: so for example. moving up the slider would begin with 0 minute 1 seconds, then 2, 3, 4 ... 59 seconds. Once it reaches 59 seconds, input boxes will read 1 min 0 sec.

Comment: @JimO. I've updated my answer. It should work now

Comment: Thanks. It's not exactly what I had in mind, but I have shortcomings explaining things :-) Thank you so much for taking your time to answer my question. If I may explain this one more time using a real example: ``https://www.armycombatfitnesstest.com/calculator`` This website has the time-slider I am looking to replicate.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value of the two input boxes by  setting the value of `D` to the value of `TIMEslider` and the value of `E` to the value of `D` times 1:

```js
TIMEslider.addEventListener("input", function() {
  D.value = this.value;
  E.value = Number(D.value) * 1;
}, false);
```

[jsfiddle with updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/mrwolferinc/f237qrzt/)